# Issue with calling parent of object onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, parent, jquery-events

Having a problem with this one-page site where the idea is you click on the links and a box slides down but it also needs a close function to bring it back up. Problem is the close button is in the element to be animated, so it needs to be called by its' parent, I presume. I've tried a variety of different ways to accomplish this but nothing seems to work. If you go to http://upsilon.lunariffic.com/~swstr0 and click About-->Sarah Weintraub, trying click the close link. Nothing happens and no errors either. So what to do? Here's an example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("li.btn-home a").click(function(){
        jQuery(this).parent.slideUp( "slow" );
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `.parent` is a chained *method*, use `.parent()`.

Comment: [slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("a.close-con").click(function(){
        jQuery(this).parents("div#panel").slideUp( "slow" );
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

`.parent()` will traverse up only one level where as `.parents()` will traverse parents of parents

> EDIT : Global selector [Requires jQuery 1.7+]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("body").on("click","a.close-con", function(){
        jQuery(this).parents("div#panel").slideUp( "slow" );
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Whats the point in wrapping an element in jquery, then retrieving the DOM element only to wrap it in jquery again? This `jQuery(jQuery(this).parents("div#panel")[0]).slideUp( "slow" );` should be this `jQuery(this).parents("div#panel").slideUp( "slow" );` No?

Comment: Usually jQuery selector returns an array of objects. so to get the first parent element i am getting it with index 0; But in this case, as it is ID, he can follow what you have given.

Comment: Yes since it is an ID `jQuery("div#panel").slideUp('slow');` is all that is needed and is way more effecient and readable. `parents()` is not needed

Comment: @AdamBell I just copied and pasted code in your site and console and tried. It seems that you are appending the panel on click of Sarah Weintraub. So instead give this code where you are appending or give a global selector.

Comment: I have edited my answer with global selector reference

Comment: Yes! That was it Bharath! Thank you so much for helping me and bearing with me on this. Same with everyone else who assisted.

Comment: New problem. Now when I click on the CLOSE link, if I click on anything else that should slide down. It no longer does.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
$(".close-con").click(function(){
    $("#panel").animate({height:"0px"},800);
});
```

**UPDATE**

I think I got the issue:-

When I am checking your source code, it was showing me below structure ie the code which I asked you to add, is added on the footer below this line "
`<script type='text/javascript' src='http://upsilon.lunariffic.com/~swstr0/wp-content/themes/swsg/js/functions.js?ver=20131209'></script>`", as shown below:-

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://upsilon.lunariffic.com/~swstr0/wp-content/themes/swsg/js/functions.js?ver=20131209'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://upsilon.lunariffic.com/~swstr0/wp-content/plugins/logo-slider/jquery.cycle.all.min.js?ver=3.9.1'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
    $("li.btn-slide a").on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var post_url = $(this).attr("href");
        var post_id  = $(this).attr("rel");

        $("#page-con").html("loading...")
                      .load(post_url, function() { // content loaded callback

            var pageconHeight = $("#page-con").height();  // Find the height of the content inside #panel
             $("#panel").animate({height: pageconHeight}, "slow"); // Animate the height of #panel

        });
    });
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("li.btn-home a").click(function(){
        jQuery("#panel").animate({height:0}, "slow");
        return false;
    });
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("a.close-con").click(function(){
        jQuery(this).parents("div#panel").animate({height:0}, "slow");
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

So, here functions.js file is creating problem with the working of close link functionality. So what you have to do take the required code ie:-

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("a.close-con").click(function(){
            jQuery(this).parents("div#panel").animate({height:0}, "slow");
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
```

and paste it above:-

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://upsilon.lunariffic.com/~swstr0/wp-content/themes/swsg/js/functions.js?ver=20131209'></script>
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: Certainly makes sense, that functions.js called is probably made by the php wp_footer(); call WordPress makes. So I placed it above that. Unfortunately, still not working. Check it out.

Comment: Well, then it'll be a problem, as now I can see some more issues, but not sure about those will make it working or not like its also showing me some issues with 
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="ie ie7" lang="en-US">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="ie ie8" lang="en-US">
<![endif]--> on top.

Comment: Is it possible that I can access your code? Then I can give it a try.

Comment: You mean create a WordPress login?

Comment: BTW, since it's WordPress, I turned off all five plugins I was using. No change. So it's not a plugin conflict.

Comment: its just jquery conflict. So I need access to the files of themes, as I have to test several parts. Did you try removing <!--[if IE 7]> <html class="ie ie7" lang="en-US"> <![endif]--> <!--[if IE 8]> <html class="ie ie8" lang="en-US"> <![endif]--> from top(I think its in header.php file)